# Window positioning in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm attempting to write a simple chat application in C using ncurses, both of which I am new to with a background in PHP. (Yes, I know.  Thanks.  I'll take that advice to heart. Please put down the guns.)

What I've attempted to do is create two windows, one for input and one for channel text, like so:

```
int termwidth = getmaxy(stdscr);
int termheight = getmaxx(stdscr);

WINDOW *channel = newwin(termwidth, termheight - 1, 0, 0);
scrollok(channel, TRUE);

WINDOW *input = newwin(termwidth, 1, termheight + 1, 0);
scrollok(input, TRUE);
```

and then set cursor position to input:

```
wmove(input, 0, 0);
```

in order to put typed input in the second window, which should occupy a single column at the bottom of the terminal, while output appears in the first window which fills the rest of the terminal's space.

Output *appears* to fill the top window (channel) properly, with the input cursor flashing in the proper place, but changing its size does not yield predictable results and typed input doesn't appear to be going into the input window at all.

The complete source is available here: http://pastebin.com/X8apHUgh

**To sum up, I am asking why input is behaving unexpectedly, and why drawing the "channel" window is yielding strange results.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, [expletive/deleted]! I'm an imbecile.  It turns out my problem was twofold:

1. I had inadvertently mixed my X and Y assignments, and
2. I had also reversed the width and height parameters in the functions.

This meant that positioning worked properly, **until** I made certain assumptions for basic positioning math.

I should add that this is partly because I was conceiving terminal positioning in terms of X/Y position, where rows/cols is the paradigm in place.  They are only partly equivalent.

*slow clap for self*

Comment: New to ncurses myself, and if I had a nickel for every time I mixed up x & y...  Sound advice to always check for these types of boners before going too in depth searching for the source of zebra hoof-sounds.